# rewrite my jquery fadein / fadeout using CSS3 only and running infinite

Tags: css, css-animations

```js
$(function() {
  $('.text1').delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.text1').delay(600).fadeOut(1500);

  $('.text2').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.text2').delay(600).fadeOut(1500);

  $('.text3').delay(10000).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text1">Lorem Ipsem</div>
<div class="text2">Lorem Ipsem</div>
<div class="text3">Lorem Ipsem</div>
```

Above is my simple jQuery animation; **simple delay -> fadeIn -> delay -> fadeOut.** However I find when trying to create a loop, for my animations to run continuously my code becomes way to large and bulky. I am wondering if it's at all possible to rewrite what I have above with CSS3 only, and then using the infinite option CSS allows.

I've gotten close with CSS below code however, I need to completely hide or fadeOut each line of text before new text shows.

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes slider {
        0%   { opacity: 0.4; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slider  {
        0%   { opacity: 0.4; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes slider  {
        0%   { opacity: 0.4; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
    
    .slider {
        -webkit-animation: slider 1s alternate infinite;
        -moz-animation: slider 1s alternate infinite;
        -ms-animation: slider 1s alternate infinite;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: This might be easier to understand if you used the Stack Snippet feature (button has `<>` in a page) so that we can run it ourselves...

Comment: Well just take a look at the jQuery. I just want what works with the top jQuery except to loop infinitely, using CSS.

Comment: Not a CSS solution,  but `$(document).ready(setInterval(function(){ //your code here//  }, 3000);` could work? Is the issue that the text all fades in/out at once, in which case you could use CSS `animation-delay`?

Comment: See? Now I don't have to copy and paste your code around; I can see it right in the question. And, people can copy the snippet to their answers, and show the solution, all without leaving Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okie Dokie, Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in other answers you can not achieve what you are asking using pure CSS solutions.

You can a solution like to an extensible approach (in case you want have many more child elements).

```js
$("#fadeinout div").on("animationend", function() {
  _this = jQuery(this);
  
   // remove animation class
  _this.removeClass("animate");
  
  // If there is no next element then go to first one otherwise choose next element
  var next = (_this.next().length < 1) ? _this.prevAll(':first-child') : _this.next();
  
  // Add class to the new element
  next.addClass("animate");
});
```

```css
#fadeinout div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 5px;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: fadeinout;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fadeinout">
  <div class='animate'></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

This is the same example with many child elements animated: https://jsfiddle.net/j4zdgopr/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can't really time the animation of multiple elements in css only. Well you could probably fake it with something like:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  opacity: 0;
}
#d1 {
  animation: d1 10s infinite;
}
#d2 {
  animation: d2 10s infinite;
}
#d3 {
  animation: d3 10s infinite;
}
#d4 {
  animation: d4 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes d1 {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 1; }
    20% { opacity: 1; }
    25% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes d2 {
    25%   { opacity: 0; }
    30% { opacity: 1; }
    45% { opacity: 1; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes d3 {
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    55% { opacity: 1; }
    70% { opacity: 1; }
    75% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes d4 {
    75% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 1; }
    95% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>
<div id="d4"></div>
```

...but I would recommend against it. First of all I don't think the timing will be reliable - ie. it will get out of sync. Second your code will most likely be even more bulky than what you have.

So I would recommend a combination of simple CSS transitions and JS like this:

```js
  var curslide = 0;
  var slides = $("#slider div");
  var nextslide = function() {
    slides.removeClass('shown');
    if (curslide >= slides.length) curslide = 0;
    slides.eq(curslide).addClass('shown');
    curslide++;
    setTimeout(nextslide, 3000);
  }
  nextslide();
```

```css
#slider div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
#slider div.shown {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
</div>
```

With this solution you can add as many frames as needed without modifying the css or js.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try playing with `animation-delay`, but I think it only applies to the first time the animation is run. After that, unless you write one animation for each `.text` element, they'll all fade in/out with the same frequency.

Would:

```
setInterval(function(){  
    $('.text1').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
    $('.text2').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
    $('.text3').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);

    $('.text1').delay(1000).fadeOut(1500);
    $('.text2').delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
}, 11500);
```

get you somewhere close?

Comment: Nah, not really. Thanks though.

Comment: What happens at the end of the animation? Are they all supposed to fade back in at the same time, and start the animation again from there?

Comment: I mean just loop, basically. Thanks for checking out my question, though.